# What is the Inverse of Projection $\pi$ ($proj$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory, projection

$x\in X=\Pi_i X_i$.

$proj_jx=x_j.$

Define: $proj^{-1}x_j=(0,0,...,x_j,...,0,...)$. That is, the $j$th term is $x_j$.

What is the formal name for $proj^{-1}$? I think I learned this before. It is either called something like "identity map" or "ideo" something.

Comment: This is natural embedding into the product; these embeddings exist when your category has a zero object, which is the case in Linear Algebra.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This seems what I was looking for. What is the symbol usually used for embeddings in category theory? Like "Im"?

Comment: @HighGPA: Usually, $\iota$ (greek letter iota) or $i$. In this case, it would likely be $\iota_j$, the $j$th coordinate embedding.

Comment: But I would absolutely avoid the notation $\mathrm{proj}^{-1}$, because that kind of notation is usually reserved for functional (two-sided) inverses when they exist.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks! Would you mind writing an answer, so I can accept that? No pushing of course.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and eventually accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is not really an inverse of the projection function, because there are many other vectors that project to the same number.

I don't think it has a fancy name; I would just describe it as **scalar multiplication with $\mathbf e_i$**.

Answer (score 1):

The latter function is commonly called a projection. In particular, it is a projection of $x$ onto (the subspace spanned by) the standard basis vector $e_j$. If you need to distinguish them, I’ve seen $proj_j$ called a “scalar projection” or “coordinate projection,” and the other a “vector projection.”

Comment: So in "vector projection", you can project a lower-dimensional vector to a higher dimension one?

Comment: Not really. That term almost always refers to an endomorphism. You could always lift the result into a higher-dimensional space, but then you won’t have the defining property $P^2=P$ for a vector projection.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inverse to the projection function. The projection function is surjective and so it has a right inverse. And as it turns out, a right inverse of a projection function is again a projection function. The formal name of your inverse projection function is "a right inverse of the projection function."

To show that it is a right inverse, observe that $\text{proj}_i(\text{proj}_i^{-1}(x)) = x_i$.

Comment: Right inverses are not in general unique, and so speaking about "the" right inverse of something is misleading.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I just fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

This is **natural embedding** into the product; these embeddings exist when your category has a zero object, which is the case in Linear Algebra. Usually, $ι$ (greek letter iota) or $i$ is used as the symbol. In this case, it would likely be $ι_j$, i.e. the $j$th coordinate embedding.

One should avoid using $proj^{-1}$, because that kind of notation is usually reserved for functional (two-sided) inverses when they exist.